# Generic bit string comparison against zero in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, bit-manipulation

Is there a way to do a non-zero bit string test without hard-coding the bit string width of 0?

For example, suppose I have two tables, Users and Features, each with masks, I want to test this:

```
SELECT u.name FROM Users u, Features f
  WHERE u.mask & f.mask;
```

matching implicit non-zero results.  However, SQL requires an explicit boolean result for `WHERE` as opposed to an implicit cast, such as this:

```
SELECT u.name FROM Users u, Features f
  WHERE (u.mask & f.mask) != 0::BIT(2048);
```

I don't want to hardcode `2048` (or whatever) in this query for a number of reasons.

Testing `expr = 0` or `expr > 0` results in a type error.  Oddly, I can test `expr = 0::BIT(1)`, but that gives the wrong answer because Postgres does not consider all all-zero bit strings to be equal.

```
select 0::BIT(2) > 0::BIT(1);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I can create a calculated zero by doing this:

```
SELECT u.name FROM Users u, Features f
  WHERE (u.mask & f.mask) != (u.mask & ~u.mask);
```

Which works but feels like an awful hack.

Any suggestions or insights?

RESULTS

I benchmarked several options provided below.  Thanks for the suggestions, Erwin!

Based on a very large data set and 100,000 queries, I found the following constructs resulted in the associated queries per second.  Hopefully someone from the Postgres team sees this and provides a generic 0 to speed things up!  Unfortunately most generic approaches seem to incur a string conversion which is quite expensive.

```
Constructs                              |  Queries / s
----------------------------------------+--------------
(u.mask & f.mask) <> 0::BIT(2048)       |  158
(u.mask & f.mask) <> (u.mask # u.mask)  |  135
(u.mask & f.mask) <> (u.mask & ~u.mask) |  125
position('1' IN (u.mask & f.mask)) > 0  |   37
(u.mask & f.mask)::TEXT !~ '^0+$'       |   27
```

Comment: What is a `non-zero bit string test`? And what exactly do you mean by `matching implicit non-zero results` Can you explain or add some examples what you want to pass and what to fail? Are your columns defined `NOT NULL`? Please add your table definition (`\d users` in psql). What is your Postgres version?

Comment: I'm looking for a non-zero result.  E.g., (B'101' & B'100') != 0::BIT(3), while (B'101' & B'010') = 0::BIT(3).  Since I'm using fields (u.mask & f.mask) I don't want to hard-code the BIT length in the query so that I can easily expand the BIT string if needed in the schema without changing many queries in the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short bitstring

To exclude cases where the [bitwise AND (`&`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-bitstring.html) returns a bitstring consisting of nothing but zeros, but the length might change (`B'000...'`), you can use a cast to `integer` (up to `bit(32)`) or `bigint` (up to `bit(64)`):

```
SELECT u.name
FROM   users u
JOIN   features f ON (u.mask & f.mask)::int <> 0;
```

When cast to integer, all of them result in `0`.
This also excludes cases where either of the columns is `NULL`. In other words, the result has to include at least one `1`.

#### Long bitstring

If your values can be longer than 64 bit, you could cast to `text` and check with a regular expression:

```
ON (u.mask & f.mask)::text !~ '^0+$'
```

Pattern explained:

`^`  .. beginning of string
`0+` .. one or more '0'
`$`  .. end of string

Or, as [the manual informs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-bitstring.html):

> The following SQL-standard functions work on bit strings as well as
>   character strings: `length`, `bit_length`, `octet_length`, `position`, `substring`, `overlay`.

Ergo:

```
ON position('1' IN (u.mask & f.mask)) > 0
```

Comment: I had tried that too, but it only works for tiny bitmaps.  In this case: SELECT 0::BIT(2048)::INT; results in: ERROR:  integer out of range.

Comment: @1.0: Right. I added alternatives for longer bitstrings.