# Check for enum types PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, binary, postgresql-10

I have a flag enum array that I create and store in the database with my program as a numeric value. Is there anyway with a Postgres function to check for whether or not a specific bit is set?

So it would be:

```
value1 = 1
value2 = 2
vaule3 = 4
....
value10 = 512
```

I want to check that 534 has the value2 flag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is the very convenient ["bitwise AND" operator **`&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) for **`integer`** numbers:

```
SELECT 534 & value2 = value2;
```

When logically "anded" with a power of 2 the same power of 2 is returned if the bit is set. (Since every power of 2 is represented by a distinct bit in the binary representation of a positive `integer` number.) Else you get 0. Compare the result with the value itself and you get either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Voilá.

Related:

- [Can I convert a bunch of boolean columns to a single bitmap in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051886/can-i-convert-a-bunch-of-boolean-columns-to-a-single-bitmap-in-postgresql/9053568#9053568)
- [Generic bit string comparison against zero in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255716/generic-bit-string-comparison-against-zero-in-postgres/20257041#20257041)

Comment: That's awesome! That's so simple... I'm a little ashamed of myself for not being able to find that lol, I guess my terms used in google just didn't produce the results I needed. Thank you.